# Are there specific paths (tunnels) inside a superconductor for which any moving electron feels a zero net Coulomb's force?

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity, coulombs-law

I want to know what the zero electrical resistance of a superconductor means. Does it mean when we connect the terminals of a battery with a superconducting wire, the electrons move within specific tunnels inside the superconductor for which the net Coulomb's force due to the nearby nuclei and the electron clouds are zero everywhere in these tunnels? Do Cooper pairs form to justify these neutral paths? If there are such paths, are they curved or straight? Do these tunnels, if exist, make the superconductor anisotropic?

Comment: From my view, this question sounds quite strange. It seems that it is not related to mainstream physics. In conventional superconductors, Cooper pairs forms due to the electron-phonon interaction and Coulomb can renormalize this interaction. Cooper pair is not localized in coordinate space and any discussion of "tunnels" inside the superconductor is irrelevant.

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov - It would be better to think of this question as "Why do electrons move without resistance in a superconductor? How does this work?" The OP has made an incorrect guess at how it works.

Comment: It is more reminiscent of chiral edge states for topological insulators rather than superconductors. Where did you see this explanation ?